# Bundle javascript & css for static website? (webpack?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webpack

I am trying to bundle all of my javascript files together, which I am using in a static HTML website. As of now, they are all unconnected, included  in different HTML files via the `script` tag.

I have now created a main.js file, which just requires all the other files, so that I can use this as my webpack entry point.

This seems to work with the files I wrote myself, but the bootstrap, tether & jquery files are throwing errors.

Note: I have not installed jquery or bootstrap via npm, I have just downloaded the javascript files, put them in the same folder and included them in the main.js file via `require`. Is there anything wrong with the way I am going about this?

```
// webpack.config.js
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./js/main'], // file extension after index is optional for .js files
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
}
```

main.js:

```
require('./jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js');
require('./tether.min.js');
require('./bootstrap.min.js');
require('./navigation.js');
require('./geschichte.js');
require('./iziToast.min.js');
require('./kontakt.js');
```

edit:

My error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:119)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:63
    at bundle.js:66
```

- although it is included, or should be.

Comment: Webpack is . You should have a "main" javascript file, so use that as an entry point.

Comment: Bundling `SASS/CSS` with `webpack` and using it should be straight forward, because you can bundle it to 1 single file and include it in your `html` page. With the `JavaScript` it's going to be tricky IF you have everything in `<script>` tags sprinkled across your `html` pages. If you can write your `JavaScript` in a way that it only has to be included on your main page, then you can use `webpack`. The easiest way to do this is by using a framework like `React`, `Vue`, `Aurelia`, `Angular`

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand why it would be more difficult with javascript though? I have tried it just now, and it does not work. Just edited my question.

Comment: Your bootstrap, tether, and jquery files are minified. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: The error is like I had never included these files. Is the minification a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't, but I find it interesting it's only those minified files you're having a problem with. In your bundle.js, do you see a comment similar to this? `* Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)`

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4, but yes, I had a comment in there. I removed it now, but still the same. I also updated this post with the specific error I'm getting.

Comment: I have also just tried it with jquery but NOT minified, and it's still the same error.

Comment: No I was just checking to see if the comment was there, that tells me webpack included it. After reviewing your latest edit to the question, your error states `jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript`. Put `require('./jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js');` after `require('./bootstrap.min.js');`

Comment: It's the other way around though: Bootstrap requires Jquery, so jquery should be included first, right? I just swapped it but it doesn't make a difference in the error message.

Comment: Sorry I always assumed most prominent dependency goes last. Doesn't appear to matter. Please see my answer below if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack.config.js:

```
// webpack.config.js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./js/main'], // file extension after index is optional for .js files
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ],
    resolve: {
       alias: {
            jquery: "../jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
        }
    }
}
```

In your main.js:
`require('jquery');`

Comment: thanks, I just tried this out, but i get an `unexpected identifier error`?

Comment: Sorry, missed a comma. Edited. Please try again.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: I get the following errors for each file: `ERROR in ./js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hs/js'
 @ ./js/bootstrap.js 1:0-17
 @ ./js/main.js
 @ multi ./js/main`

Comment: I apologize, i'm not familiar with your directory structure. You'll need to play around with the relative path of that jquery file. Maybe try changing the path in the alias field to this? `jquery: "./jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have mentioned this, but I had already adjusted the path. Maybe there's still a typo then?

Comment: That error is basically telling you it's not able to find `jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js` at the entry point (`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hs/js` directory.) As mentioned, you'll need to play around with that alias value and make sure it's pointing to the correct path and that your jquery file actually exists there.